# Run sequence of tasks, one after the other

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I have a sequence of tasks, where each one depends on the output of the previous one. I'd like to represent this as a single `Task` object, whose result is the output of the end of the sequence. (If the tasks didn't depend on one another then I could do it in parallel and I would use `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`.)

I'd like to be able to implement this method:

```
static Task<TState> AggregateAsync<T, TState>(
    IEnumerable<T> items,
    TState initial,
    Func<TState, T, Task<TState>> makeTask);
```

How can I efficiently run the tasks one after another in sequence? I'm using C# 4.0 so I can't use `async`/`await` to do it for me.

**Edit:** I could write `AggregateAsync` like this:

```
static Task<TState> AggregateAsync<T, TState>(IEnumerable<T> items, TState initial, Func<TState, T, Task<TState>> makeTask)
{
    var initialTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => initial);
    return items.Aggregate(
        initialTask,
        (prevTask, item) =>
            {
                prevTask.Wait(); // synchronous blocking here?
                return makeTask(prevTask.Result, item);
            });
}
```

But surely I'll get a batch of tasks, each of which blocks synchronously waiting for the one before it?

Comment: The [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) nugget adds support for `async` / `await` in .Net 4.0 projects, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Would the `ContinueWith` method help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easy way (using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`):

```
static async Task<TState> AggregateAsync<T, TState>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items,
    TState initial,
    Func<TState, T, Task<TState>> makeTask)
{
  var state = initial;
  foreach (var item in items)
    state = await makeTask(state, item);
  return state;
}
```

The hard way:

```
static Task<TState> AggregateAsync<T, TState>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items,
    TState initial,
    Func<TState, T, Task<TState>> makeTask)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TState>();
  tcs.SetResult(initial);
  Task<TState> ret = tcs.Task;
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    var localItem = item;
    ret = ret.ContinueWith(t => makeTask(t.Result, localItem)).Unwrap();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Note that error handling is more awkward with the "hard" way; an exception from the first item will be wrapped in an `AggregateException` by each successive item. The "easy" way does not wrap exceptions like this.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - it looks like `TaskExtensions.Unwrap` is the magic method. And the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917(v=vs.100).aspx). is similar to my situation.

Comment: Thanks for the `.Unwrap` "trick". Also, can't the first three lines of your "hard way" be replaced with `Task.FromResult(initial)`? Is there any difference?

Comment: @dcastro: Yes, except that `FromResult` isn't available on .NET 4.0. But that is logically what it's doing.

Comment: I'm confused by the requirement for `Unwrap`. Seems like silly design on MS' part.

Comment: @Gusdor: It makes sense to me; if you have a task returning a task of state, the correct type *is* `Task<Task<TState>>`, which you can `Unwrap` into a plain `Task<TState>`. There are certain situations where the `Task<Task<TState>>` is exactly what you want. The reason it's a bit awkward is because we're doing asynchronous programming in .NET 4.0 (when the `Task` type was primarily intended for parallel programming).

Comment: @StephenCleary right, i get it now. Unwrap returns a `Task<TState> `(instead of a `Task<Task<TStart>>`) but still waits for the unwrapped `Task` to finish. That is handy!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Task.ContinueWith`. The `task` you see in the code below, represents the previous (completed) task, and you can fetch its result to execute the second task, and so on.

```
T item1 = default(T);
T item2 = default(T);
Task<TState> task1 = makeTask(initial, item1);

//create second task
task1.ContinueWith(task => makeTask(task.Result, item2).Result,
                     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I missed this part

> I'd like to represent this as a single Task object, whose result is the output of the end of the sequence.

In order to do that, you just have to return a reference to the result of the last `ContinueWith` call.

```
Task<State> aggregate = task1.ContinueWith(
                                  task => makeTask(task.Result, item2).Result,
                                  TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

var res = aggregate .Result; //wait synchronously for the result of the sequence
```

Comment: Having done this in F# and JS I wanted a `ContinueWith` that can create a new task - that is, `Func<Task<T>, Task<TResult>>`. But there's only `Func<Task<T>, TResult>`.

Comment: What do you mean? I may have misunderstood you.. I'm positive you can easily implement a method with the given signature using the sample I provided, and your own implementation of `makeTask`.

Comment: Just chain all your tasks with `.ContinueWith` and the result of that will be a single Task instance you can wait for (for example using Task.Result as dcastro shows). The tasks will be done in order. That is - `task1.ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...)` or something similar.

Comment: How would your second example apply to an arbitrary sequence? If I `return secondTask;`, I get a `Task<Task<T>>`; if I `return thirdTask;` I get `Task<Task<Task<T>>>`, and so on. I updated the question with code that I think achieves what I want, but with blocking.

Comment: @TimRobinson my bad, i've fixed my examples to return `Task<State>` instead of `Task<Task<State>>`. In this code, there is no blocking. By the time you call `.Result` on the previous task, the task has already been ran to completion.

Comment: @TimRobinson: How so? `task.ContinueWith (_ => task.Result).ContinueWith (_ => 12).ContinueWith (_ => 43)` returns a `Task<int>`.

Comment: @Luaan in my previous code, my lambda was returning `Task<TState>` which in turn would make ContinueWith return a `Task<Task<TState>>`. I changed my lambdas to simply return `TState` instead.

Comment: @Luann `firstTask.ContinueWith(_ => CreateSecondTask(firstTask.Result)).ContinueWith(secondTask => CreateThirdTask(secondTask.Result)` given `Task<int> CreateSecondTask(int firstResult)` and `Task<int> CreateThirdTask(int secondResult)`.

Comment: @dcastro I think this blocks synchronously, the same as `Wait` in the question: `makeTask(task.Result, item2).Result`

Comment: @TimRobinson Give it a try. The first `Result` in that expression does not block, because the result is already available. The second `Result` only blocks the thread on which the `ContinueWith` task is running, which doesn't really matter.

Comment: @dcastro Go from a single async sequence in the example to 1000 of these async sequences, running in parallel. I can't afford to have 1000 threads blocking.

Comment: Can anyone post an example of using this pattern please? I am trying to understand it. Thanks.