# Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I need to run multiple async tasks in a console application, and wait for them all to complete before further processing.

There's many articles out there, but I seem to get more confused the more I read. I've read and understand the basic principles of the Task library, but I'm clearly missing a link somewhere.

I understand that it's possible to chain tasks so that they start after another completes (which is pretty much the scenario for all the articles I've read), but I want all my Tasks running at the same time, and I want to know once they're all completed.

What's the simplest implementation for a scenario like this?

Answer (score 609, accepted):

Both answers didn't mention the awaitable [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___):

```
var task1 = DoWorkAsync();
var task2 = DoMoreWorkAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

The main difference between [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) and `Task.WhenAll` is that the former will block (similar to using `Wait` on a single task) while the latter will not and can be awaited, yielding control back to the caller until all tasks finish.

More so, exception handling differs:

**`Task.WaitAll`**:

> At least one of the Task instances was canceled -or- an exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances. If a task was canceled, the AggregateException contains an OperationCanceledException in its InnerExceptions collection.

**`Task.WhenAll`**:

> If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks.
>
> If none of the supplied tasks faulted but at least one of them was canceled, the returned task will end in the Canceled state.
>
> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the resulting task will end in the RanToCompletion state.
> If the supplied array/enumerable contains no tasks, the returned task will immediately transition to a RanToCompletion state before it's returned to the caller.

Comment: When I try this my tasks run sequentially? Does one have to start each task individually before `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` ?

Comment: @Zapnologica `Task.WhenAll` doesn't start the tasks for you. You have to provide them "hot", meaning already started.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So what will your example do? Because you have not started them?

Comment: @Zapnologica In my example, both methods are the one to kick off the tasks. `Task.WhenAll` asynchronously waits for both of them to complete, but their execution happens concurrently.

Comment: is it the same to call   Await Tasks.Task.Run(()=>dowork) for each function sequentially?

Comment: @batmaci No, `await` on each `Task` will await each task *one at a time*. using `Task.WhenAll` will concurrently wait for the completion of all tasks.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thank you very much! It is so simple but it helped me a lot today! Is worth at least +1000 :)

Comment: if you are not going to use `await Task.WhenAll(...)` then you can just `StartNew` on all the tasks and let it be

Comment: @Pierre I'm not following. What does `StartNew` and spinning new tasks have to do with asynchronously waiting on them all?

Comment: Nothing at all :)

Comment: If there is an exception thrown inside of DoWorkAsync() or DoMoreWorkAsync() before the await calls are reached, won't the exception be lost? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/because-this-call-is-not-awaited-the-current-method-continues-to-run

Comment: @Ryan AFAIR Exceptions that happen before the first await point are thrown synchronously.

Comment: Another good example of using Task.WhenAll is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/97803) and it shows getting result from each afterwards.

Answer (score 139):

You could create many tasks like:

```
List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
foreach(...)
{
   var LastTask = new Task(SomeFunction);
   LastTask.Start();
   TaskList.Add(LastTask);
}

Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
```

Comment: I would recommend WhenAll

Comment: Is it possible to start multiple new threads, at the same time, using the await keyword rather than .Start() ?

Comment: @MattW No, when you use await, it would wait for it to complete. In this case you would not be able to create a multi-threaded environment. This is the reason that all the tasks are waited at the end of the loop.

Comment: Downvote for future readers since it isn't made clear that this is a blocking call.

Comment: See the accepted answer for reasons why not to do this.

Answer (score 70):

You can use [`WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return an awaitable `Task` or [`WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) which  has no return type and will block further code execution simular to [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) until all tasks are completed, canceled or faulted.

|  | [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0) | [`WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state* | A task with the faulted state will be returned. The exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks. | An [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) will be thrown. |
| *None of the supplied tasks faulted but at least one of them was canceled* | The returned task will end in the [`TaskStatus.Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-5.0) state | An [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) will be thrown which contains an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception?view=net-5.0) in its [`InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions?view=net-5.0#System_AggregateException_InnerExceptions) collection |
| *An empty list was given* | An [`ArgumentException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=net-5.0) will be thrown | The returned task will immediately transition to a [`TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-5.0) State before it's returned to the caller. |
|  | Doesn't block the current thread | Blocks the current thread |

**Example**

```
var tasks = new Task[] {
    TaskOperationOne(),
    TaskOperationTwo()
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
// or
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you want to run the tasks in a particular/specific order you can get inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20424498/6583901) answer.

Comment: sorry for coming to the party late but, why do you have `await` for each operation and at the same time use `WaitAll` or `WhenAll`. Shouldn't tasks in `Task[]` initialization be without `await`?

Comment: @dee zg You are right. The await above defeats the purpose. I ll change my answer and remove them.

Comment: yes, that's it. thanks for clarification! (upvote for nice answer)

Answer (score 32):

The best option I've seen is the following extension method:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, Task> action) {
    return Task.WhenAll(sequence.Select(action));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
await sequence.ForEachAsync(item => item.SomethingAsync(blah));
```

Or with an async lambda:

```
await sequence.ForEachAsync(async item => {
    var more = await GetMoreAsync(item);
    await more.FrobbleAsync();
});
```

Comment: I did this overload to get the return type:
`public static Task<R[]> ForEachAsync<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, Task<R>> action)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(sequence.Select(action));
        }`

Answer (score 16):

Yet another answer...but I usually find myself in a case, when I need to load data simultaneously and put it into variables, like:

```
var cats = new List<Cat>();
var dog = new Dog();

var loadDataTasks = new Task[]
{
    Task.Run(async () => cats = await LoadCatsAsync()),
    Task.Run(async () => dog = await LoadDogAsync())
};

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(loadDataTasks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: If `LoadCatsAsync()` and `LoadDogAsync()` are just database calls they are IO-bound. `Task.Run()` is for CPU-bound work; it adds additional unnecessary overhead if all you are doing is waiting for a response from the database server. Yuval's accepted answer is the right way for IO-bound work.

Comment: @StephenKennedy could you please clarify what kind of overhead and how much it can impact performance? Thanks!

Comment: That would be quite hard to summarise in the comments box :) Instead I recommend reading Stephen Cleary's articles - he's an expert on this stuff. Start here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Answer (score 8):

Do you want to chain the `Task`s, or can they be invoked in a parallel manner?

**For chaining**
Just do something like

```
Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...);
Task.Factory.StartNew(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...);
```

and don't forget to check the previous `Task` instance in each `ContinueWith` as it might be faulted.

**For the parallel manner**
The most simple method I came across: [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx)
Otherwise there's [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) or you can even use `WaitHandle`s for doing a countdown to zero actions left (wait, there's a new class: [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx)), or ...

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but your suggestions could have been explained a little more.

Comment: @drminnaar which other explanation beside the links to msdn with examples do you need? you didn't even click on the links, did you?

Comment: I clicked on the links, and I read the content. I was going for the Invoke, but there were a lot of If's and But's about whether it runs asynchronously or not. You were editing your answer continuously. The WaitAll link you posted was perfect, but I went for the answer that demonstrated the same functionality in a quicker and easier to read way. Don't take offense, your answer still provides good alternatives to other approaches.

Comment: @drminnaar no offense taken here, i am just curious :)

Comment: Parallel.Invoke works like a charm... didn't know about it until I got to this answer... Thx!

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it with an array **Func<>**:

```
var tasks = new Func<Task>[]
{
   () => myAsyncWork1(),
   () => myAsyncWork2(),
   () => myAsyncWork3()
};

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(task => task()).ToArray()); //Async    
Task.WaitAll(tasks.Select(task => task()).ToArray()); //Or use WaitAll for Sync
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep it as Task Array?

Comment: If your not careful @talha-talip-açıkgöz your execute the Tasks when you didn't expect them to execute. Doing it as a Func delegate makes your intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

might like to take a look at below link which explains which explains best practice for await async.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

```
Use this...       Instead of this...  When wishing to do this...
await               Task.Wait  
                    Task.Result       Retrieving the result of a background task
await Task.WhenAny  Task.WaitAny      Waiting for any task to complete
await Task.WhenAll  Task.WaitAll      Waiting for all tasks to complete
await Task.Delay    Thread.Sleep      Waiting for a period of time
```

Answer (score -1):

I prepared a piece of code to show you how to use the task for some of these scenarios.

```
    // method to run tasks in a parallel 
    public async Task RunMultipleTaskParallel(Task[] tasks) {

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    // methode to run task one by one 
    public async Task RunMultipleTaskOneByOne(Task[] tasks)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length - 1; i++)
            await tasks[i];
    }
    // method to run i task in parallel 
    public async Task RunMultipleTaskParallel(Task[] tasks, int i)
    {
        var countTask = tasks.Length;
        var remainTasks = 0;
        do
        {
            int toTake = (countTask < i) ? countTask : i;
            var limitedTasks = tasks.Skip(remainTasks)
                                    .Take(toTake);
            remainTasks += toTake;
            await RunMultipleTaskParallel(limitedTasks.ToArray());
        } while (remainTasks < countTask);
    }
```

Comment: how get the results of Tasks? For example, for merge "rows" (from N tasks in parallel) in a datatable and bind it to gridview asp.net ?

Answer (score -1):

There should be a more succinct solution than the accepted answer.  It shouldn't take three steps to run multiple tasks simultaneously and get their results.

1. Create tasks
2. await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
3. Get task results (e.g., task1.Result)

Here's a method that cuts this down to two steps:

```
    public async Task<Tuple<T1, T2>> WhenAllGeneric<T1, T2>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        return Tuple.Create(task1.Result, task2.Result);
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(DoWorkAsync(), DoMoreWorkAsync());
var DoWorkResult = taskResults.Result.Item1;
var DoMoreWorkResult = taskResults.Result.Item2;
```

This removes the need for the temporary task variables.  The problem with using this is that while it works for two tasks, you'd need to update it for three tasks, or any other number of tasks.  Also it doesn't work well if one of the tasks doesn't return anything.  Really, the .Net library should provide something that can do this

Comment: it's not a bad idea, and would probably be given a better rating if you fix the usage example; you probably meant to call `WhenAllGeneric` instead of `WhenAll`.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using the [async/await pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), you can run several tasks in parallel like this:

```cs
public async Task DoSeveralThings()
{
    // Start all the tasks
    Task first = DoFirstThingAsync();
    Task second = DoSecondThingAsync();

    // Then wait for them to complete
    var firstResult = await first;
    var secondResult = await second;
}
```

Comment: This approach introduces the risk of leaking a fire-and-forget task, in case the `first` task completes with failure before the completion of the `second` task. The correct way to `await` multiple tasks is the `Task.WhenAll` method: `await Task.WhenAll(first, second);`. Then you can `await` them individually to get their results, because you know that all have completed successfully.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Is there a problem with leaking fire-and-forget tasks? It seems that for a console application at least, you don't get much benefit from waiting ten minutes on WhenAll to find out that you misspelled the input file name.

Comment: It depends on what this fire-and-forget task does. In the best case it just consumes resources, like network bandwidth, that are going to waste. In the worst case it modifies the state of the application, at a time when it's not expected to happen. Imagine that a user clicks a button, they get an error message, the button is re-enabled, and then the `ProgressBar` continues moving up and down by the ghost task... This never happens by any tool provided by Microsoft (`Parallel`, PLINQ, TPL Dataflow etc). All these APIs do not return before all internally initiated operations are completed.

Comment: If a failure of one task makes the result of another task irrelevant, then the correct course of action is to cancel the still-running task, and `await` it to complete as well. Awaiting each task sequentially, as your answer suggests, is rarely a good idea. If you decide that leaking fire-and-forget tasks is OK for your use case, then symmetrically a failure on `second` should also leak the `first`. Your code doesn't support that. Its leaking behavior is asymmetric.