# Async web service call return bool and output parameter .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

**Async web service call  return bool and output parameter .net.**
I have one web service method which takes 2 input parameter and one output para meter. This method return type is bool.
I am calling this webservice method asynchronously in a loop.
But when I try to get the out put parameter value using call back method or task.Wait it does not wait. It completes the execution as the web service return type is bool.
How should I capture the output parameter value for each call. If I delay the task i am getting few more data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the code? Web services do not have output parameters. All data is returned in a single SOAP response object. It's the proxy that makes it look as if there are return values and parameters. I suspect that by *asynchronous* you mean something different to what anyone else means - if you get *any* result back, the service call has *already* completed

Comment: Are you confusing polling with asynchronous client calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood, you want to call the same method asynchronously from a web service multiple times, and right now you're doing it from a for loop?

Can you take a look at this answer:

[Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete)

and use [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to wait for all of them to complete?