# How does C# Task.WaitAll() combine object states into one?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

Given a simple Hotel entity as an example:

```
class Hotel
{
    public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; }
    public int StarRating { get; set; }
}
```

Please consider the following code in C# 5.0:

```
public void Run()
{
    var hotel = new Hotel();
    var tasks = new List<Task> { SetRooms(hotel), SetStars(hotel) };
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Debug.Assert(hotel.NumberOfRooms.Equals(200));
    Debug.Assert(hotel.StarRating.Equals(5));
}

public async Task SetRooms(Hotel hotel)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    hotel.NumberOfRooms = 200;
}

public async Task SetStars(Hotel hotel)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    hotel.StarRating = 5;
}
```

Both calls to Debug.Assert() pass successfully. I don't understand how after both tasks have completed, the instance of Hotel contains the assignment from both the methods that run in parallel.

I thought that when `await` is called (in both `SetRooms()` and `SetStars()`), a "snapshot" of the hotel instance is created (having both `NumberOfRooms` and `StarRating` set to 0). So my expectation was that there will be a race condition between the two tasks and the last one to run will be the one copied back to `hotel` yielding a 0 in one of the two properties.

Obviously I am wrong. Can you explain where I'm misunderstanding how await works?

Comment: Where did you get the idea about the "snapshot" from? :)

Comment: From the description of the state machine created by the compiler I guess...? :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I thought that when await is called (in both SetRooms() and
>   SetStars()), a "snapshot" of the hotel instance is created

Your `Hotel` class is a reference type. When you use async-await, your method is transformed into a state-machine, and that state-machine hoists the *reference* to your variable onto it. This means that both state-machines created are pointing at *the same `Hotel` instance*. There is no "snapshot" or deep copy of your `Hotel`, the compiler doesn't do that.

If you want to see what actually goes on, [you can have a look at what the compiler emits](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f: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) once it transforms your async methods:

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(C.<SetRooms>d__1))]
public Task SetRooms(Hotel hotel)
{
    C.<SetRooms>d__1 <SetRooms>d__;
    <SetRooms>d__.hotel = hotel;
    <SetRooms>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    <SetRooms>d__.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <SetRooms>d__.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start<C.<SetRooms>d__1>(ref <SetRooms>d__);
    return <SetRooms>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
}
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(C.<SetStars>d__2))]
public Task SetStars(Hotel hotel)
{
    C.<SetStars>d__2 <SetStars>d__;
    <SetStars>d__.hotel = hotel;
    <SetStars>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    <SetStars>d__.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <SetStars>d__.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start<C.<SetStars>d__2>(ref <SetStars>d__);
    return <SetStars>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

You can see that both methods hoist the `hotel` variable into their state-machine.

> So my expectation was that there will be a race condition between the
>   two tasks and the last one to run will be the one copied back to hotel
>   yielding a 0 in one of the two properties.

Now that you see what the compiler actually does, you can understand that there really isn't a race condition. It's the same instance of `Hotel` which is being modified, each method setting the different variable.

---

**Side note**

Perhaps you wrote this code just as an example to explain your question, but if you're already creating async methods, I'd recommend using `Task.WhenAll` instead of the blocking `Task.WaitAll`. This means changing the signature of `Run` to `async Task` instead of `void`:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    var hotel = new Hotel();
    await Task.WhenAll(SetRooms(hotel), SetStars(hotel));
    Debug.Assert(hotel.NumberOfRooms.Equals(200));
    Debug.Assert(hotel.StarRating.Equals(5));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yuval-itzchakov. What is the advantage of using `Task.WhenAll()` over `Task.WaitAll()`?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` is non-blocking, thus asynchronously yielding control to the calling method, as opposed to `Task.WaitAll` which synchronously blocks. Also, exception handling is a little different. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete/25010220#25010220) question for more.

Comment: Seeing as I will immediately call `Wait()` on the the Task` returned from `Task.WhenAll()`, does the advantage still hold?

Comment: @urig No, it doesn't :) Any reason you must immediately block on it?

Comment: @urig, you should never call `Wait()` on an async task, you're almost guaranteed to get a deadlock if you do it from the UI thread. In this case it works, but only because both methods use `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque You're right, but *almost guaranteed* really depends on the existence of a custom `SynchronizationContext` or not. If he's running this from a unit-test or a console application, that won't be an issue. But you're absolutely right about the fact that blocking on async code is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, that's why I said "if you do it from the UI thread" ;)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Only reason is I need to end the chain of awaits somewhere, no? :)

Comment: FYI, this is running in ASP.net. Also, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is intentional.

Comment: @urig You don't need to block with `Wait`. Make your action return a `Task<T>` and you can await in the controllers action as well