# Compute several values in parallel. Wait for all threads to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

What is the idiomatic and fastest way to do the following in C#? Say I have a class that has three values (it is always three values so pre allocating 3 tasks is ok):

```
public class AggregateValues
{
    public double A { get; set;}
    public double B { get; set;}
    public double C { get; set;}
}

public AggregateValues Compute()
{
     //How do I parallize these?
     AggregateValues av = new AggregateValues();
     av.A =  ComputeA();
     av.B =  ComputeB();
     av.C =  ComputeC();

     //Wait for ComputeA, ComputeB, ComputeC to be done

     return av;
}

public double ComputeA()
{
    // Complicated code
}

public double ComputeB()
{
   // Complicated code
}

public double ComputeC()
{
   // Complicated code
}
```

Comment: If you can use asyncs, the WaitAll/WhenAll methods will be the cleanest way to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to wait for all tasks to complete. A simple solution to your case is provided below.

```
public AggregateValues Compute()
{
    //How do I parallize these?
    AggregateValues av = new AggregateValues();

    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => av.A = ComputeA());
    Task taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => av.B = ComputeB());
    Task taskC = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => av.C = ComputeC());

    //Wait for ComputeA, ComputeB, ComputeC to be done
    Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);

    return av;
}
```

await on [Task.WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete) can also be used to wait for all tasks to be completed.

Comment: Thanks that works. I am wondering how efficient "Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => av.A = " I guess I can always statically allocate them.

Answer (score 2):

If `ComputeA`, `ComputeB`, and `ComputeC` aren't asynchronous (and they aren't in your code because they return `double` instead of `Task<double>`), then you can use [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public AggregateValues Compute()
{
    AggregateValues av = new AggregateValues();
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => { av.A = ComputeA(); },
        () => { av.B = ComputeB(); },
        () => { av.C = ComputeC(); });
    return av;
}
```

In your scenario, Parallel.Invoke is slightly better than [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) because Parallel.Invoke can reuse the calling thread for one of the tasks.

Comment: I am going to time to see which one is faster.