# Async methods to load datas from a database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm building a Visual Studio .NET application in c# with 2 databases and Entity Framework. 
At first, I thought it would be better to load the most used datas in static Lists when the app is launched, but it was a bit too long, so now I try to use Tasks. I have one method per table I want to load, and I call them in a more general method :

```
public static void fillConstantes()
    {
        new Task(FillFiches).Start();
        new Task(FillCustomers).Start();
        new Task(FillEmployees).Start();
        new Task(FillContact1).Start();
        new Task(FillServiceItems).Start();
        new Task(FillServiceLine).Start();
    }
```

The fact is, if if I try to access the datas in another class and the task isn't finished, it crashes, obvisouly. 
So, I was wondering if there's a good way to check if the tasks are done, are if I just have to check if it worked whenever I try to retrieve datas ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Task t = new Task(() => { });
  t.Start();
```

you can use t.IsCompleted for your purpose

Comment: Thanks ! I think it'll do the job ! And is there a way to wait for them all ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete