# Waiting for Tasks to finish

Tags: c#, async-await

I have 2 simple methods and I want process to not continue until they are finished completely. Because of this I used await Task.WaitAll(tasks);
but compiler is giving me error in this line:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from ' 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
```

Why should I convert this manually by myself? I thought this would be done by the compiler...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Count1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Count 1 " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public static void Count2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Count 2 " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public static async Task Run()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        Task t1 = Task.Run(()=>Count1());
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => Count2());

        tasks.Add(t1);
        tasks.Add(t2);

        await Task.WaitAll(tasks);  //ERROR IS THROWN HERE
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really need WaitAll, you want to convert the list to an array, like that: `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`

Comment: Task[] tasks = new Task[] { t1, t2 };    Task.WaitAll(tasks);   worked

Comment: @Lyrk: While it works, it involves blocking in an async method, which is generally a bad idea. If you make your `Run()` method non-async, and make it return `void`, that's okay...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect you meant [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7) rather than [`WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.7). `WaitAll` is a *blocking* call that returns all the results synchronously, when the original tasks have completed. You can't await that result, as it's not a task.

`WhenAll` is an *asynchronous* call that returns a task which completes when all the original tasks have completed. You can await that.

If you change the end of your `Run` method to:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
```

... you'll see the tasks finish and then the completion message.

Comment: Thank you. WhenAll worked. I did not know WhenAll returns a Task object.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use it as :**

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

- Requires params of Task, so you have to use toArray() of linQ.
- or you can also use : `Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);` as @Jon Skeet suggested.

> The main difference between Task.WaitAll and Task.WhenAll is that the
> former will block (similar to using Wait on a single task) while the
> latter will not and can be awaited, yielding control back to the
> caller until all tasks finish.
>
> For More Detail : [You Can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010220/6061907).