# Waiting for the multiple async process to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, wait

I want to perform a set of operations that involves different asynchronous processes writes into a single file and once the write is complete another async processes waiting for the completion of write performs the uploading of the same file to a different service. All the operations returns void.

Following is the approach I am trying

**API Layer**

```
private static async Task writeToFile(string data){
...
     await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(myFile, data);

}

private static async Task sendFile(string data){
     ...
     var properties = await FileIO.GetPropertiesAsync(myFile, data);
     if(properties.Size > = 0){
       await FileProcessor.sendFile(myFile);
     }
    ....
}
```

From my app, I am calling the **WriteFile** method multiple times followed by a **SendFile** operation. Due to the problem in the nature of my approach of handling the async tasks, it ties to perform the send immeditely after my first WriteToFile is performed. But I like to make the sendFile wait till all my WriteFile calls are complete.

Could someone suggest me (or correct me) with the approach on how to make these async task (sendFile) wait till all the data writing is complete ?

Thank you.

Comment: what happens currently? does it work? you say " it fails to send the file correctly." - what does that mean, ***exactly***? how are `writeToFile` and `sendFile` orchestrated relative to each-other? does one code-path call the `await writeToFile(...); await sendFile(...);`? or...?

Comment: sendFile gets called immediately after my first writeFile call, as it is async in nature. How can I create a wait for all the previous writeFile call invokes before the sendFile is called.

Comment: Marc, Thanks for your quick response. These are the API implementations which are being called from my UWP App. The API has been implemented within a Singleton which exposes externally APIs as obj.Write(data) and obj.Send() that internally calls these methods mentioned above

Comment: "How can I create a wait for all the previous writeFile call invokes before the sendFile is called" - by calling `await` against each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete)

Comment: Can I use this way to force the task synchronous.... ? 
Task.Run(()=>WriteFile(...)).Wait; 
I am afraid this might block the main Thread or UI

Answer (score 2):

First define each of your **WriteFile** method as task and set to a variable :

```
var task1 = WriteFile(...);
var task2 = WriteFile(...);
var task3 = WriteFile(...);
var task4 = WriteFile(...);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);
```

Then call your **SendFile** and use await for result.

```
await SendFile(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my scenario I am not sure of how many times the tasks will be called. Reason is end user might invoke the API any number of times that API will in turn invoke the tasks you mentioned as task1, task2, ... 
 Example: 
 obj.callWriteFile( );  // this inturn calls the API WriteFile
 obj.callWriteFile( );
 obj.callWriteFile( );

 obj.callSend();

Comment: so you must know how many API Calling from user to send file first, for example set timeout to wrap all request for **WriteFile** then call **SendFile**.