# Asp.Net core 2.1 await doesn't yield control to caller on 2nd run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-2.1

I am in the process of making all of my database operations asynchronous. However, I don't seem to get the desired results of asynchrony.

e.g. -

I am inserting 100 rows to a table in a database in a loop. The function that does this is a async function. It doesn't seem to yield control to its caller when its awaiting. The code is below -

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/logtest")]
public async Task<JObject> logTestAsync()
{
    JObject retval = new JObject();
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;

    Task t = BulkLogInsertAsync();


    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
    retval["Exec_Time"] = dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalMilliseconds;

    await t;

    DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Now;
    retval["Await_Time"] = dt3.Subtract(dt2).TotalMilliseconds;
    return retval;
}

private async Task BulkLogInsertAsync()
{
    List<Task<int>> allTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
         allTasks.Add(LogInsertAsync("insert into logs values (getdate() , 'custom' , 'sample message. ', 'Log.bills', 'callsite1', '', '', '')"));
        //allTasks.Add(LogInsertAsync("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';"));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
private async Task<int> LogInsertAsync(string cmd)
{
    int res = 0;
    using (SqlConnection hookup = new SqlConnection(@"[mycnstr]"))
    {
        Task connectionOpeningTask = hookup.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, hookup))
        {
            await connectionOpeningTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            res = await sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        hookup.Close();
    }
    return res;
}
```

When I call the API /api/logtest the very first time, I seem to get desired results with exec_time much less than await_time (0.2s vs 4s)

However from 2nd run onwards I get await_time much less than exec_time (4s vs 0.2s) which is making me believe code ran synchronously.

Also the same code in a console app using .net framework 4.6.1, gives desired results continuously. and no I did not restart the console app. Ran the BulkLogInsertAsync in a do while loop :-)

Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: you might get help with this link. give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @CodeConstruct thanks for the help, but I think I am chaining the tasks properly here, the problem seems to be with the openAsync and ExecuteNonQueryAsync, somehow , they are not yielding control on subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set a couple of things straight:

1. Threads are not magical resources that are just laying there, w8ing for work
2. The higher number of threads you have, more resources you´ll need to manage them
3. Asynchrony, although very helpful is not an easy thing

Ok, first of all, your app starts with a predefined number of w8ing threads (usually number of cores*2, if i recall correctly, can find the damn msdn article). If you request threads and you´re using under this limit, you get them instantaneously, otherswise, you'll have to w8 500ms (cant find the article)

Second, [async is not parallel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)!

Third, in your code, whenever you use await, it awaits! so, i suggest you refactor await on `OpenAsync`, chaining with `ContinueWith` and only use the await once in your code, because, as it is right now, your `using`'s are preventing `async` from working properly... you will have to manage the connections and disposals on your own if you want the code to run asynchronously

Edit1:

There are 2 types of threads: IO Threads and Worker threads. In your code, what you need is IO threads to w8 for the database... if you need more context on this, you can [start here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb)

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` is useless in ASP.NET Core: [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)

Comment: How are the `using`'s preventing `async` from working properly?

Comment: I still don't get it why then the very first time I run this code, I get the desired result, exec_time much less than await_time. The code behaves in a perfect async way, it yields to calling function on await, its only on 2nd time and onwards, the await doesn't yeild to caller.

Comment: also not to mention that code works perfectly fine and as expected in a console application !