# Assigning multiple tasks to to multiple thread

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have multiple **REST API** calls which I want to do in parallel way.
E.g.

I have a REST API call **CreateData()**. I want to create 1000 datas in server which is adapted for multi-thread operation in 4-5 parallel threads.

I am C++ developer and know how multithreading works in C++. I am quite naive in C# coding. I know about async tasks but dont have idea how to acheive the above said task.

```
var response = await Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
```

Right now I am doing it in sequence where one by one I am creating the data in a single thread once I have recieved response of previous **CreateData()**. It is impacting the perfomance badly and taking hell lot of time.

I want to create say 5 threads which will do the REST API calls in parallel manner for all the 1000 users.

Comment: `Dataflow`, `Parallel.For`, `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are assigning `response` to the result of the `Task.Run` which also requires the `Task` to complete in some regard. This happens automatically when compiled because you are using the keyword `await`.

If you prefer, you can just assign `response` to the running `Task` itself and keep going.  Of course I wouldn't call it `response` anymore.  Let's say you do that and call it `task1` instead.

```
var task1 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
```

Now your code will continue running and `task1` will just represent the running `Task`.

If you had 5 you could do them all like it sounds that you want.

```
var task1 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
var task2 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
var task3 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
var task4 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
var task5 = Task.Run(()=>CreateData());
```

Now you can also wait for all of these tasks to complete at the same time with `Task.WhenAll` method.

```
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5);
```

---

So to sum it up.

The `await` keyword does some compiler magic and basically puts a callback in that place of the method (assigning the rest of the method to be a continuation when the `Task` is complete) and ALSO assigns the `Result` of that `Task` to the variable (if the `Task` has a result).  There is a lot to unpack here; I don't believe a short answer really justifies what's happening.

Without using the `await` keyword then you simply assign the `Task` itself to the variable.

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar I did make a huge mistake in my examples; which I fixed just now.  I told you not to use ```await``` if you wanted to assign the ```Task``` itself but in the examples I was using ```await```; which wouldn't have worked prior to my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010220/4209924

OR

You can do something like this.

```
    public async Task CreateData()
    {
        // your logic here with await
    }

    public async Task GetData()
    {
        var data1 = CreateData();
        var data2 = CreateData();
        var data3 = CreateData();
        var data4 = CreateData();
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { data1, data2, data3, data4 });
    }
```