# run multiple task and await for all tasks completes

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I need to run multiple task to access to database and to wait to all task finished to obtain the result and assign it to my viewmodel, i try many sample but i have never have the result, any help please, this my code

```
var model = new AggregationViewModel();
var loadDataTasks = new Task[]
{
    Task.Run(async () =>model.Alive =  await _repository.GetCountAsync<filter>(Predicate)),
    Task.Run(async () => model.Delay = await _repository.GetCountAsync<Flight>(predicate.And(x => x.Status == "refused")))
};
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(loadDataTasks);
    foreach (var item in loadDataTasks)
    {

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete)

Comment: I try same sample but my model.Delay and model.Alive always 0, and i don't know why

Comment: Your codce is missing the most essential part: how do you call this?  Post the complete call chain.

Comment: This is my main call, do i need something else?

Comment: ok sorry for that

Comment: "my main call" doesn't mean anything, you are still missing the most important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
 var task1 = _repository.GetCountAsync<filter>(Predicate);
 var task2 = _repository.GetCountAsync<Flight>(predicate.And(x => x.Status == "refused"));

 await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); //wait both tasks to finish

 model.Alive = await task1;
 model.Delay = await task2;
```

PS: the function, which the above code is placed, is needed to be async for the above scenario.

Comment: There's a typo: `WaitAll` -> `WhenAll`

Comment: i can't add await before WaitAll and i had never the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var model = new AggregationViewModel();

//----------------------------------------
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
//Add CountA
tasks.Add(_repository.GetCountAsync<filter>(Predicate));
//Add CountB
tasks.Add(_repository.GetCountAsync<Flight>(predicate.And(x => x.Status == "refused")));

//----------------------------------------
// Create a task with "allTasks" name to wait to complete all tasks
Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try {
    // Wait to compelete "allTask"
     allTasks.Wait();
}
catch(AggregateException) 
{}

//----------------------------------------
//Working on the results

if (allTasks.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
   model.CountA=allTasks.Result[0]
   model.CountB=allTasks.Result[1]
}
// Display information on faulted tasks.
else {
    foreach (var t in tasks) {
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
     }
}
```

Comment: what's t in the if please?

Comment: @user1428798, I have used `allTasks` in the condition section of the `if` block. Also `t` variable in `for` block points to each one of your defined tasks. Do you have any problem?

Comment: in the first part is not defined in the if

Comment: Sorry I corrected it to `allTasks`. Check it now please.