# Is there a scope that wait for all Async methods inside it without the methods waiting for each other in C#?

Tags: c#, kotlin

I'm writing an async method ListenAndProcess that wait for a tcp message, recursively call itself, process the message, then terminate. At one point in time, all the ListenAndProcess methods will terminate, which then I would like to do some cleaning up. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?
I'm thinking something like this:

```
private async void CreateNewClient(TcpListener listener)
{  
   var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
   WaitAllMessages{ // <-- how to achieve this?
      ListenAndProcess(client.GetStream());
   }
   client.Dispose();
}

private async void ListenAndProcess(NetworkStream networkStream)
{
    try
    {
        var counted6C = 0;
        var message = new Byte[100];
        var i = 0;
        while (counted6C < 2)
        {
            await networkStream.ReadAsync(message, i, 1);
            if (message[i] == 0x6C)
            {
                counted6C++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // message listening finished, listen to another message
        ListenAndProcess(networkStream);
        await Process(message, networkStream);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Listen and process error: {0}", e);
    }
}
```

I can do

```
private async void CreateNewClient(TcpListener listener)
{  
   var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
   await ListenAndProcess(client.GetStream());
   client.Dispose();
}

private async Task ListenAndProcess(NetworkStream networkStream)
{
    try
    {
        var counted6C = 0;
        var message = new Byte[100];
        var i = 0;
        while (counted6C < 2)
        {
            await networkStream.ReadAsync(message, i, 1);
            if (message[i] == 0x6C)
            {
                counted6C++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // message listening finished, listen to another message
        var listenTask = ListenAndProcess(networkStream);
        await Process(message, networkStream);
        await listenTask;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Listen and process error: {0}", e);
    }
}
```

but won't that keep all the instances of method ListenAndProcess and can lead to stackoverflow (Sorry if I'm wrong)? I think coroutineScope in Kotlin can achieve this, but I don't know any C# equivalent.

I tried adding all the new tasks to a list and use Task.WhenAll on the list but it waited only for the first task. Program.cs (minimal reproducible example):

```
List<Task> list = new List<Task>();
list.Add(A(0));
await Task.WhenAll(list); // <-- only one instance of A in the list when this is called 
Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up");

async Task A(int number)
{
    if (number == 3)
    {
        return;
    }
    await Task.Delay(500);
    list.Add(A(number + 1));
    Console.WriteLine("A - {0}", number);
}
```

Expected output:

```
A - 0
A - 1
A - 2
Cleaning up
```

Actual output:

```
A - 0
Cleaning up
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete) answer you question?

Comment: I am still struggling to see how that would make sense. What's the recursion for? Where is the stopping criterion? As-is, it looks to me as if you just could as well `DoSomething()` in a loop ... (roughly).

Comment: There is also nothing "async" about this if you are just awaiting the next level of recursion - which actually executes synchronously ... I am confused. And I _think_ this may even run into Thread Pool exhaustion or a deadlock before you even get to a StackOverflow (which you _will_ if nothing else). That leads me to assume this is an X-Y Question. Why don't you tell us what the _problem_ is instead of asking for a fix to a (alleged) _solution_ ?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama It doesn't unfortunately. I tried using Task.WhenAll with a list of task created by instances of A but by the time WhenAll was called, there was only one task in the list and WhenAll waited only for that task.

Comment: _"there was only one task in the list"_ - how could that be unless you removed them from the list? Even `var tasks = new List<Task>() { Task.CompletedTask, Task.CompletedTask }; await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` will use the two completed tasks in the list.

Comment: ^^ That means you _have_ at least compilable code. So, you _could_ in fact produce a [mre], right?

Comment: @Fildor I added the actual problem and a minimal reproducible example, would you check them out?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I added a minimal reproducible example, in which each instance of A would wait for 500ms (pretend the method A is doing some work) before calling itself and adding the task to the list. When Task.WhenAll is called, there's only one Task in the list because 500s has not passed and A hasn't call itself yet D:

Comment: Why are you using recursion? It seems to be asking for truoble in your scenario. Why not use BackgroundTasks.Services features to monitor for network activity and process when necessary, without recursion? I run several console apps that use this approach and they work perfectly for the problem. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: What does Kotlin have to do with the question? Besides, both `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WaitAll` do what the title asks. The code has critical bugs though, like `async void` return types and won't compile. As long as `async void CreateNewClient` is used, there's no way to await `CreateNewClient` itself

Comment: ^^ As I suspected: I am on the "no recursion" team. And for client disposal: better use a `using` or at least a `try-finally`, so the client gets disposed regardless of exceptions happening.

Comment: @stemixrf Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into BackgroundTasks.Services. I used recursion because I want to read any new message while processing old ones, which may take some time.

Comment: @Fildor I will definitely use **using** to auto dispose if possible, but with the way the methods are being written, the client will be disposed without waiting for ListenAndProcess to finish. Maybe if there's a better way to write these methods...

Comment: Well, the way I am used to from "ye olden days" is that you `AcceptTcpClient` in a loop and then hand off the client handling to a dedicated thread. Today you'd probably want to do the equivalent in Tasks.

Comment: @Fildor do you receive and process multiple messages from 1 client simultaneous or do you just leave them in the stream for later processing? Maybe I should just do 1 at a time ...

Comment: I tend to decouple reading from processing unless backpressure is explicitly wanted. That is: I would read and decode to my protocol until I have a complete message. That message will be posted to a pipeline and reading continues ... so 1 client - 1 reader, no concurrency in _that_, but there _may_ be more than 1 client concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but won't that keep all the instances of method ListenAndProcess and can lead to stackoverflow (Sorry if I'm wrong)?

No, async methods will be rewritten to a statemachine, so it can be resumed from the threadpool after each await. This means the callstack will be short, but you will have an awful lot of tasks.

I would recommend a iterative solution, I do not really see any advantage to using recursion for a task like this, perhaps something like this:

```
private async Task ListenAndProcess(NetworkStream networkStream){
  Task processTask = Task.CompletedTask;
  while(!<END CONDITION>)
  {
   ...
   while (counted6C < 2)
   {
       ...
       await networkStream.ReadAsync(message, i, 1);
       ...
   }
   await processTask;
   // Assumes the Process method is only writing to the stream
   processTask = Process(message, networkStream);
  }
}
```

This give a single task to be awaited.

It may allow the `ReadAsync` and `Process` to be done concurrently, depending on how `Process` is implemented. Reading and writing can be done concurrently for a [networkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-8.0), but if `Process` reads from the stream you need to be really careful:

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required

You need to figure out when reading should be finished. I can't see anything in your current code for that, so I assume you intend for some exception to signal that the reading is finished ?

If you want more concurrency it is common to use some form of queue to allow some work to run sequentially: [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels), [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), [LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-8.0), a simple [blockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-8.0), and probably many more. All should have some way to (a)wait for the queue to be emptied so you can shut it down cleanly.

I would also suggest reading [How Async/Await Really Works in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/) for a more in dept explanation about how async works. Stephen cleary also have a good article about [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: I may not understand you entirely... am I right to say the tasks you mention are statemachines saved in memory waiting to finish? So the second approach is till a no-go? And what does resumed from the threadpool mean, are the statemachines "saved in the threadpool" somehow? As for the Process method, it may or may not write to the stream, depending on the message, but it still probably not safe so I will need to implement a queue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SpaceFish Maybe take the time and read through [Stephen Cleary's Blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) :D

Comment: @SpaceFish Updated the answer, and added some links that should explain the details about async/await.

Comment: @JonasH thanks for the links and the solution guys, it's not ideal as each processTask still need to wait for the previous one, but I think it'll do.

Comment: @SpaceFish Since writing cannot be done concurrently to the same stream you will be somewhat limited in what you can do. But Dataflow or Channels might be suitable to allow concurrent *processing*, while still reading and writing from a single thread each.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding all tasks you wanted

```
List<Task> list = new List<Task>();
list.Add(A(0));
list.Add(A(1));
list.Add(A(2));
list.Add(A(3));
await Task.WhenAll(list);
Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up");
```

**Edit**

Use `async Task` instead of `async void`

Commented by : *Panagiotis Kanavos*

Comment: It still showed the actual output

Comment: The problem is that `CreateNewClient` is an `async void`. There's no reason to add tasks to a list, just change it to `async Task` and actually await the method.

Comment: _"Always use async Task, void doesn't works with async"_ - that's not what Panagiotis said and it's also not entirely correct. `async void` has legitimate use cases. Only this is not one of them.