proper use of async/await in DotNetty?
The echo server example in the DotNetty repository calls Task-returning methods IChannelHandlerContext.WriteAsync(object message) and IChannelHandlerContext.CloseAsync() from void methods without ever awaiting them. Is this acceptable? What happens to any exceptions thrown from the Task-returning methods? What if I want to call WriteAsync multiple times...is it safe to do so (is ordering guaranteed somehow?)? Or would I need to call Task.Wait() / Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() or make the calling methods async void and then use await when calling the async methods?

async void is always 'fire and forget, just as calling a Task returning metod without await.

"is order guaranteed?" - if order is needed, either await each task, or do ContinueWith - as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422026/run-sequence-of-tasks-one-after-the-other/20424498#20424498
